# Webstorm 7 и поддержка COMPASS

Tags: ide, sass, webstorm

В новой версии Webstorm появилась поддержка *COMPASS*, но что-то у меня не получается настроить. У меня Винда и не совсем понятно где использовать пути до `compass.bat`, а где просто для compass, два разных файлы в `ruby\bin`.
В общем если есть люди, которые уже пользуются в вебшторме компассом, то поделитесь инструкциями. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806938/how-to-use-compass-in-phpstorm)  но на винде тоже не смог запустить пока